# Exponential Generating Function of guests at k tables

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions

**Question:**  Let $g_n$ be the number of ways in which $n$ people can sit down at an unspecified number of tables that are arranged in a line, so that if $k$ tables have people around them, then those will be the first $k$ tables in the line. Two seating arrangements are considered identical if a person has the same left neighbor in both of them, and each person sits at the same table in both of them. Find the exponential generating function $G(x)$ of $g_n$.

I have been reading about exponential generating functions but am still quite confused by them. From my understanding, we need $G(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n!} x^{n}$. Here $a_{n}$ is counting the ways to impose some structure on an $n$ element set. I believe the structure I am looking to count is the following: the number of ways we can break the permutation $(12345...n)$ into $k$-cycles. Could I have some help?

**edit:** I see now it's not exactly the structure I described. Since something like $(12)(34)$ and$(34)(12)$ will be different seating arrangements but are the same cycle.

I have tried to describe some $g_{n}$ here. When $n=1$ $g_n = 1$, when $n =2$ I believe $g_{2} = 3$ since we have the arrangements $(1)(2),(12),(2)(1)$.

**More progress:** If $k$ is the amount of tables filled, it seems that we have a relation like $g_{n+1,k+1} = (k+1) g_{n,k} + n g_{n,k+1}$. But I wouldn't know how to turn this into an EGF.

If $k$ is fixed we could write the EGF like $\sum_{n} \sum_{k} g_{n,k} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Wait I think $g_{n} = {n \choose k}$

Comment: Nevermind this is not right.

Comment: I am not exactly counting permutations according to their cycles though am I? Because $(1 2)(3 4)$ and $(34)(12)$ describe the same permutation however these are different arrangements.

Comment: Oh I see you've made some changes, could you explain to me what you did to get $(1-z)^{-u}$? What are $u,z$ here?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I read too quickly. My mistake, please ignore me :)

Comment: The reasoning is similar to the answer by @angryavian, only, the egf is $e^{uf(x)}=e^{-u\log(1-x)}=(1-x)^{-u}$. Sorry, I am short on time at the moment. If you want more details I can provide them later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence can be found on OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/A007840). The EGF can be found there as well.

---

The EGF for cycles is
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = - \log (1-x).$$

Then the EGF of sequences of cycles is then
$$1+f(x)+(f(x))^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-f(x)} = \frac{1}{1+\log(1-x)}.$$

---

Some intuition on why this last step works: consider the coefficient of $x^5$ in $1+f(x)+(f(x))^2+\cdots$. It will be the sum of the coefficients of $x^5$ in $f(x), (f(x))^2,\ldots,(f(x))^5$ respectively.

- The contribution from $f(x)$ is $\frac{4!}{5!}x^5$, and indeed $4!$ counts the number of ways to seat $5$ people at one table.
- The contribution from $(f(x))^2$ is
- $$\left(\frac{3!}{4!}\cdot \frac{0!}{1!} + \frac{2!}{3!} \cdot
     \frac{1!}{2!} + \frac{1!}{2!} \cdot \frac{2!}{3!} + \frac{0!}{1!}
     \cdot \frac{3!}{4!}\right)x^5 = \frac{\binom{5}{4} 3!0! +
     \binom{5}{3} 2!1! + \binom{5}{2} 1!2! + \binom{5}{1}0!3!}{5!}x^5,$$
  and indeed the expression in the numerator is the number of ways to seat $5$ people at two tables.
- The contribution from $(f(x))^5$ is $x^5 = \frac{5!}{5!} x^5$, and indeed there are $5!$ ways to seat $5$ people at $5$ tables.
- etc.

You can prove more formally that this works out in general.

Comment: Are you table to explain why we do the composition or no?

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} = -\log{(x+1)}$

Comment: @Boots [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm)

Comment: Is something like http://math2.org/math/expansion/log.htm mistaken then

Comment: @Boots Yes, I think the table at the bottom is incorrect.

Comment: Also shouldn't the EGF be $\sum \frac{f(x)^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: @Boots That would be true if the tables were not ordered. But the wording of your post ("tables arranged in a line" and "sits at the same table") suggests that the tables are ordered.

Comment: But it's asking for an EGF which is in the form I said.

Comment: @Boots I don't understand your comment. I have given you the EGF for your question, which is $\frac{1}{1-f(x)}$ assuming the tables are ordered. If the tables are unordered, then it should be $e^{f(x)}$ as in your earlier comment.

Comment: I guess I don't get why that is the EGF